# Git how to pull the update from original repository and keep my own changes

Tags: git, github, fork, branch, clone

should i clone-branch or fork-clone-branch.

the original repository is Tom's project in github, but i want to make some changes, and keep my changes while can keep updating or pulling update from original Tom's project.

can someone show me what is the right workflow?

thanks!

i tried to clone it and branch it

expecting to keep my own changes, but also can keep updating the original prject.

Comment: Either way will work, it will just affect which repo that is initially assigned `origin` but you are free to change and add remotes as you like after the initial clone. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008292/23118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113010/23118) answer for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to clone the repository and then create and work on your own branch.

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

Commit your work on this branch and whenever you want to pull changes from the original repository, stash your changes (to avoid errors)

```
git stash
```

And then fetch and pull changes from the remote branch.

```
git fetch origin
git pull origin master
```

This way you can will be able to keep your changes, while getting the latest changes from origin.